# Do I need to run my notification service extension before archiving the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

For my app, I have added Notification Service extension to support Rich Notifications and show image thumbnails/preview right in Push Notifications. I have two targets for Staging and Production environments and for these targets I have added two Notification Service Extensions attaching the corresponding target during creation.

- **Do I really need to create separate extensions for both targets?**

I have noticed that rich notifications only work when I run the extension first on a device and then archive the app, if I don't run the extension and archive the app directly the notifications don't work as expected.

- **Why do I have to build the extension first and then archive the app to make it work?**

Below is a screenshot of targets in my app:

[image]

Comment: No i dont think so because notification service its selft one of the target. you need to create it's own provisiona profile and set properly.

Comment: @NitinGohel thanks, yes this is the expected behavior, I have signed the extension with proper profiles keeping the parent app id in mind.

Comment: @VinayJain Did you add two separate extensions for two targets? If not then how did you add parent target while creating the extension? I am also facing the same problem as I also have two targets for staging and live.